# Multiple videos for a player In Agora Unity SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I have agora sdk integrated in my current project. I create a prefab having video surface component for a user whenever he/she joins and video is rendered on that. Now if I want to create another prefab and render the video of the same player on that too then it gets messed up and the video for that player doesn't work. The main thing, I can't have multiple video surfaces rendering a single user's video. The reason for this is that at some stage in my game I want to display video in rectangle and somewhere else I want to display in a round masked image so I create separate prefabs. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is actually possible and got tested many times. Please share how you manage the VideoSurface creation and assignment of the joined remote user.